# Согласование прилагательного с существительными

Tags: согласование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно согласовать прилагательное и существительные в тексте. Корректно ли написать:

1. "Не слышал более **эстетичных** музыки и песен, чем у..."

Или правильнее будет, например:

2. "Не слышал более **эстетичной** музыки и песен, чем у..."
3. "Не слышал более **эстетичных** песен и музыки, чем у..."

Или все варианты верны?

Спасибо!

Comment: Лучше всего звучит второе.

Comment: Песни входят в музыку (вокально-инструментальная музыка), в таком случае "музыки и песен" не очень корректно. Если считать музыку инструментальной разновидностью в отличие от вокальной (одно из значений), то музыка есть в песнях. Тогда надо: *музыки и пения* (как в словаре).

Answer (score 1):

Все кривые, потому что эстетика - это чувство вкуса. Чувство либо есть/либо нет, не может быть *более* или *менее* эстетичное что-то, что-то может быть или эстетичным(нравится), или не эстетичным(не нравиться). Это первый момент.

Второй момент "эстетичная музыка" - так не говорят, говорят "музыкальная эстетика" - чувство красоты в рамках какого-то вида искусства. Музыка - это не объект(хотя сегодня музыка может быть синонимично музыкальному треку, но объект трек, а не музыка). Музыка не может быть эстетичной или не эстетичной, потому что это искусство, направление, а не вещь. Эстетичной/не- может быть картина, ваза... Хотя эстетичная песня - тоже криво, говорят благозвучная песня, приятная, мелодичная. "Эстетичная" применяют скорее к изобразительному искусству, ну или к видимому - эстетичный танец, эстетичное сальто, но не к музыке. У музыки нет видимой формы.

Почему музыка еще не такая? Ну потому что музыка может быть гармоничной, и она уже вроде эстетическая получается. А дисгармония - не эстетична. Эстетична потому что гармонична, эстетика следствие гармонии. Не стоит путать диссонансы и консонансы - которые латинизмы, потому что диссонансы, несмотря на "неблагозвучность" и вроде как "дисгармоничность" могут быть эстетичными. То есть можно сказать эстетичный диссонанс, но нельзя сказать эстетичная дисгармония.

Вот еще кусочек, кажущийся мне любопытным:

> Термин диссонанс пришел к нам тоже из музыки. Консонанс (мягкое и слитное, согласное звучание) и диссонанс (жесткое и напряженное) являются противоположными понятиями теории музыки, [музыкальной гармонии](https://nad-suetoi.livejournal.com/494895.html).

То есть диссонанс и консонанс существуют внутри тории музыкальной гармонии. И далее:

> В свою очередь термин "гармония" в музыке имеет ряд значений: это, прежде всего, музыкально-эстетическое понятие - слаженность звуков или "благозвучие"; это композиционно-техническое понятие - объединение звуков в созвучия и их закономерное последование; гармонией также называется научная и учебно-практическая дисциплина, изучающая звуковысотную организацию музыки, созвучия и их связи. Гармония как техническое средство и как дисциплина важны для грамотного (профессионального) создания и исполнения музыкальных произведений и изучения этих процессов.

> Начальная история гармонии в музыке как раз и знаменуется открытием, изучением и развёртыванием свойств консонанса и диссонанса в ладовых системах Древней Греции, Древнего Китая, Индии, стран Ближнего Востока.

Ну и так далее, советую почитать статью про музыку, гармонию, диссонансы и консонансы, чтобы разобраться в музыкальной эстетике и с чем её едят.

Вот это еще нравится:

> По большому счёту природа музыки - не звуковая, хотя и строится на физических закономерностях, а интонационная.

А касательно фразы: раньше я не знал, что бывает настолько эстетичное и мелодичное звучание, как у группы ... в песнях ...

Comment: *Эстетичной/не-* — это нечто, тянет на лингвистический мем.

Comment: я старался) с подачи-таки *тыквенного*